# Fourier transform of heat equation

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I need to solve following partial differential equation with Fourier transform numerically.

$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \nabla(c\nabla T)
$

where T is temperature, c heat conductivity and t is time.

Now the problem is c itself has space dependence. Had it not been after Fourier transform equation would look like 
$
\frac{\partial \tilde T}{\partial t} = -k^2c\tilde T
$

How should Fourier transform of first equation look like?

What I am doing is as follows:

1. Take Fourier transform of T. Multiply corresponding values of c(in real space) and T (in Fourier space). i.e. evaluate $g = k\cdot i \cdot c \cdot\tilde T$
2. Take $g$ back to real space. Now $g = c\nabla T$
3. Take $g$ back to Fourier space . Evaulate $f = k \cdot i \cdot \tilde g$
4. Take $f$ to real space. Now $f$ should be $\nabla c \nabla T$

But results of the above procedure are not matching with Finite Difference approach. What am I missing here? Using convolution theorem seems difficult. Is using convolution theorem the only option?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Why do you think it should match finite difference? Even if $c$ was constant I doubt they match.

Comment: @timur, there is difference of nearly factor of two in the results of FFT and Finite difference. In sufficiently small time step results of FFT and Finite difference must be identical.

Comment: I don't think the results are supposed to match. Here's why I think so. (I could be wrong.) If you use finite difference, which method do you use for the time variable? If you use an explicit method, the domain of influence/dependence of one cell is only limited to nearby cells in the case of finite difference. You expand the domain of influence/dependence of one cell to be the whole domain by taking Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate $\nabla(c\nabla T)$ in Fourier space, you need to do the following. Suppose that you are given $\hat T$, which is the Fourier image of $T$.

1. Compute $\hat g(k)=ik\hat T(k)$. This corresponds to real space gradient.
2. $g= \mathrm{IFT}\,\hat g$, the inverse Fourier transform.
3. $f=cg$.
4. $\hat f = \mathrm{FT}\,f$, the Fourier transform.
5. Compute $\hat r(k)=ik\cdot\hat f(k)$. Note the scalar product. This corresponds to real space divergence.
6. $r= \mathrm{IFT}\,\hat r$, the inverse Fourier transform.

Now you have $r = \nabla\cdot(c\nabla T)$. I think in practice, you don't need step 6, because the left hand side $\partial T/\partial t$ can be computed in Fourier space directly from $\hat T$. You can also write all the steps in one formula
$$
\frac{\partial\hat T}{\partial t} = ik\cdot\mathrm{FT} (c\cdot\mathrm{IFT}(ik\hat{T})).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I can't comment below your question, so I'm posting a comment here:  The fourier transform will be a convolution, which is a bit nasty to work with, i.e. you get that:

$$\mathcal{F}(c T) = \mathcal{F}(c) \star \mathcal{F}(T)$$

Here $\mathcal{F}(f) = $ Fourier transform of $f$. Note that

$$  \mathcal{F}(c) \star \mathcal{F}(T) (s) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty}  \mathcal{F}(c)(s - t) \mathcal{F}(T) (t) dt$$

This will couple all the Fourier modes together.  In my humble opinion, the Fourier transform is going to be a bit nasty numerically, though maybe still do-able.  Unfortunately, I am not able to suggest another alternative.

Comment: c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: thanks dblazevski. your explanation was useful.